# Oracle Ano por extenso

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11c

Esta pergunta é permitida ?

Simples , em tese

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YEAR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=PORTUGUESE') FROM DUAL;
```

Deveria retornar Dois mil e vinte e um.
Mas retorna TWENTY TWENTY-ONE

Versão 11
Nls da sessão está inglês
como os do Banco

```
nls_language        AMERICAN    AMERICAN
nls_date_language
```

O que pode estar errado ?

[Fonte](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

Comment: A própria documentação diz que o retorno será sempre em inglês.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, com a função abaixo você consegue retornar os meses e os dias em português.

`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = Portuguese;`

Porém no seu caso, o ano acredito que teria que ser tratado com case. Exemplo:

`SELECT CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') = 'TWENTY TWENTY-TWO' THEN 'Dois mil e vinte e dois' end as ANO_POR_EXTENSO FROM DUAL;`

Comment: Até a 11, onde fiz isto tive de fazer um CASE. Não testei em outras versões.